# How to use the private and public key generated from Aws Kms GenerateDataKeyPair method to sign and verify a message

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-kms

I am trying to generate a private key and public key using Aws kms GenerateDataKeyPair method which returns me a private key and public key in ByteBuffer format, now i want to sign and validate a message without using kms client. Can anyone please help me how can i use this private and public key which are in byteBuffer format to sign and validate? Thank you

I tried using some libraries like cipher and Signature which are java libraries, these libraries expect the private key to be in the format of “PrivateKey” key object in order to sign and “PublicKey” key object in order to verify. But there is no way to convert from bytebuffer to PrivateKey or PublicKey format

Answer (score 0):

Try using BouncyCastle. The trick is working with the DER encoding provided by AWS in the ByteBuffer for both the plaintext private key and the public key.

From the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/kms/AWSKMSClient.html#generateDataKeyPair-com.amazonaws.services.kms.model.GenerateDataKeyPairRequest-)

"The private key is a DER-encoded PKCS8 PrivateKeyInfo."

See [org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.PrivateKeyInfo](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/394093cbea19148a41dcd7e1780037a8230f43b6/core/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/asn1/pkcs/PrivateKeyInfo.java#L60)

"The public key is a DER-encoded X.509 SubjectPublicKeyInfo."

See [org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.SubjectPublicKeyInfo](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/394093cbea19148a41dcd7e1780037a8230f43b6/core/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/asn1/x509/SubjectPublicKeyInfo.java#L22)

And finally [org.bouncycastle.openssl.PemKeyPair](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/394093cbea19148a41dcd7e1780037a8230f43b6/pkix/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/openssl/PEMKeyPair.java#L6)